# Get Recommendation from LinkedIn API returns empty map [:] as response

Tags: grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have created a web application from which I am trying to get recommendations of a user from his/her LinkedIn Profile using URL

String url="**https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender))?format=json**"

When I am using this URL in the
[Api Explorer](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) it works fine. And gives output:-

```
{   "recommendationsReceived":  {
    "_total": 2,
    "values":  [
       {
        "id": 558598601,
        "recommendationText": "xxx is among the best team players I ever worked with.  He has handled client effectively with smooth operations. I had always seen him as person with solution mindset and always look for  solution rather than thinking about the problem. ",
        "recommendationType":  {
          "code": "colleague"
        },
        "recommender":  {
          "firstName": "XXX",
          "id": "YYYY",
          "lastName": "XXX"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": ZZZZ,
        "recommendationText": "XXX is one of the most dedicated person at work.I always him with a flexible attitude and ready to adapt himself in all situation.I have seen him work all night to catch up all the deadlines and deliver on time ."
        "recommendationType":  {
          "code": "colleague"
        },
        "recommender":  {
          "firstName": "XXX",
          "id": "YYYY",
          "lastName": "XXXX"
        }
      }
    ]   } }
```

***The problem comes, when I am using this URL in my Developer app.It doesn't give any error just simple return an empty map [:] as output in response***

***Irrespective of these recommendation fields, I successfully get the user basic profile data such as email, id, image,firstName,lastName.Means my code is working for other fields well but not for these recommendation* fields***

To find the solution, I did some internet  surfing and find a link of Linked API docs

> [Linked API Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields)
>
> As per Docs following selection of profile fields are only available
>   to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with
>   LinkedIn program:
>    Recommendation Fields

I already created a LinkedIn Developer account to get key & Secret
So how do I apply and get approval for Apply with LinkedIn Recommendation Fields.
I already have seen  the LinkedIn support but can't find the way to ask question to the Linked Developer help support

Please suggest me the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long internet surfing,I have found something fruitful that, I have to fill up a form to get these fields.Here is the [form](https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr)

along with its procedural details

Answer (score 0):

You can use just recommendations-received keyword. Try the following link. I am getting all recommendations details with this link.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(recommendations-received)?format=json

Comment: I also had tried this one, but it doesn't work.Thanks for responding